# Deleting content from all cells in a range not working, why not?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am selecting a range of cells, then hit delete and only the cell in the upper left deletes the content. In the past all cells contents would be deleted. I am sure I change a setting without knowing it, but not sure what it is. Please assist.

Comment: Using the delete key "DEL" rather than the backspace "<--" should work, so long as you have not started typing or otherwise activated the first selection of the selected range. If you are using the DEL key already let me know and I will have another look. You can also right-click and select "Clear Contents" to achieve the same result.

Comment: I agree with Justin. If you use “Backspace", the expected behavior is to delete only the content of the first line.